# How to make a portable file with Rcpp::plugins(openmp) which can be Rcpp::sourceCpp'ed

Tags: r, openmp, rcpp, r-package

As a simple, likely memory bound, example, suppose I am looking at this C++ file which I want to `Rcpp::sourceCpp`:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>

// [[Rcpp::plugins(openmp)]]
// [[Rcpp::export(rng = false)]]
double sum_par(Rcpp::NumericVector x, int n_threads){
  double out(0.);
  double *xp = &x[0];
  int const nx = x.size();
#ifdef _OPENMP
#pragma omp parallel for num_threads(n_threads) reduction(+:out)
#endif
  for(int i = 0; i < nx; ++i)
    out += xp[i];
  return out;
}

/*** R
set.seed(1)
x <- rnorm(100)

sum    (x)
#R> [1] 10.88874
sum_par(x, 1L)
#R> [1] 10.88874
sum_par(x, 2L)
#R> [1] 10.88874
*/
```

This file will not compile when the compiler does not support OpenMP. The question is how to create a portable example which users can `Rcpp::sourceCpp` in manner that will work for users with and without OpenMP support.

#### The Concrete Example

I recently published the psqn package on CRAN. There is [an example in the package](https://github.com/boennecd/psqn/blob/ea7a70a6cf02aeedf3533efd2551719094968d27/inst/mlogit-ex.cpp) which shows how to use the shared headers in the package. However, this yields an error when I `Rcpp::sourceCpp` the file in [this unit test](https://github.com/boennecd/psqn/blob/ea7a70a6cf02aeedf3533efd2551719094968d27/tests/testthat/test-cpp-api.R#L35) on CRAN's checks with macOS.

I have tried to wrap the `Rcpp::sourceCpp` call in `try` and then use a version of the C++ file on an error which does not include the `[[Rcpp::plugins(openmp)]]` line but for some reason `try` does not work with `Rcpp::sourceCpp`. I gather I can make a configuration file like in RcppArmadillo but I have never (successfully) done this before with a R package.

Comment: You may have to write a generalized version of `sourceCpp()` with a generalized `R CMD COMPILE` etc under it.  As far as I know R solves that problem for itself by relying on the (possibly empty) `Make` variable(s) `SHLIB_OPENMP_CFLAGS` and `SHLIB_OPENMP_CXXFLAGS` and `SHLIB_OPENMP_FFLAGS`.

Comment: Or you make it simpler and make the example be "empty" on macOS.  The setup issues of macOS in particular with respect to OpenMP are well documented.  There is strictly nothing the Rcpp team can do here.  Sadly.  We like OpenMP too.

Comment: Yes, I was figurering one could use something like the `SHLIB_OPENMP_CXXFLAGS` make variable. The easiest is just to use `testthat::skip_if` on macOS.

Comment: I am sure that you have thought about the behavior of `sourceCpp`, but could you not check at the package installation whether OpenMP is available. If it is not and without knowing the details of the backend, could you then simply ignore the  `Rcpp::plugins(openmp)` possibly with a message about that it OpenMP is not present? That may be more like the experience of working with packages from CRAN. I am sure there are good arguments for the current behavior though!

Comment: We have done these things six different ways and they almost aways break in subtle forms. See the commit log for RcppArmadillo's `configure.ac` for a history over the years.  To the best of my knowledge there is no Free Lunch (TM) here.

Comment: Got it. I was sure you had considered something like this before.